# Removing Fellow & Sync buttons using javaScript worked well, while it will fail to hide the share Button

Tags: 2013, javascript, master-page, page-layout

I have wrote the following three scripts at the end of my master page, to remove the Fellow,Sync and Share buttons:-

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("HideBrandingsuite");
function HideBrandingsuite()
{
document.getElementById('site_follow_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
<script type= "text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("HideBrandingsuite2");
function HideBrandingsuite2()
{
document.getElementById('ctl00_SyncPromotedAction').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
<script type= "text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("HideBrandingsuite3");
function HideBrandingsuite3()
{document.getElementById('ctl00_site_share_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

This will remove the sync and fellow buttons, but still the Share button appear, although when I used the developer tool inside IE it mentioned  that the Share button id is  = 'ctl00_site_share_button' as mentioned inside my code ? Any idea how to hide the Share button??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer using css rather than javascript.

In your custom css file put this line to hide the buttons:

```
#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight a[id$="_SyncPromotedAction"] 
{
   display: none !important;
}

#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight a[id$="_share_button"] 
{
   display: none !important;
}
```

It should work

Comment: thanks but how to remove the Fellow link in this way . if i do not want to use java Script ?

Comment: Which is the fellow button? Do you mean Follow button? In that case use #RibbonContainer-TabRowRight a[id$="_follow_button"]{ display:none !important }

Answer (score 0):

You can hide them by using below javascript

```
$(document).ready(notRequiredElement);

function notRequiredElement() {
    $("a[id$='_share_button']").css("display", "none");
    $("a[id$='_SyncPromotedAction']").css("display", "none");

}
```

Where `id$='_share_button'` represent any element that end with _share_button

You can find more selector http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/